# Is there a way to change value of cells in a filtered column?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to do a kind of database with google-sheets but I don't find a way to change cells value of a whole column while my column is filtered.
For example, if I filter column D to have all int > 0, can I add 1 to the all cells in column E for them ?

### [image: My image]

Comment: did you try to expand your filter view to E?

Comment: The Picture doesn't include E column.
Please provide enough data so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to modify the last column of the `Filter` and add it to the E column "doesn't appear in your example." in the formula it self

> **Paste** this formula in `G1` to get the output with one formula.

```
={ArrayFormula(A1:C1), D1&" + "&E1 ; FILTER(A2:C,D2:D>0,D2:D=INT(D2:D)), ArrayFormula({ QUERY({FILTER(A2:E,D2:D>0,D2:D=INT(D2:D))}, "Select Col4 ") + QUERY({FILTER(A2:E,D2:D>0,D2:D=INT(D2:D))}, "Select Col5 ") }) }
```

[image]